upgrade-assistant cli and only update the project to SDK style
What is the commandline way of calling upgrade-assistant WITHOUT changing the targetFramework?
usual way:
upgrade-assistant upgrade my.csproj -o feature.sdkstyle -o Inplace **-f net8.0** --non-interactive
I've looked for an option to do this, or a flag to -f that keeps the framework version, in documentation, at microsoft (artices), but no luck.
and the -f flag seems to be mandatory.
Anyone know how to do this, with the cli?
I've tried looking for docs about upgrade-assistant cli,
tried the help, and tried finding the cli tool's github repo, but no luck.
Help image attached: upgrade-assistant cli help

tip from abpiskunov@github (I have filled in this answer from there):
This feature exist for a while already.
If you run "upgrade-assistant upgrade" and select classic project it would how you all available upgrade types including "only sdkstyle".
Command line will be
"upgrade-assistant upgrade MyProj.csproj -o feature.sdkstyle --non-interactive"
blog post about it: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant-august-2023-update/
